# AWK print between two characters

Tags: awk, grep

When I try this command:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s sketch*.zip "https://www.sketch.com/downloads/mac/" |\
    grep 'download.sketchapp.com/sketch-' | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'
```

The output is:

```
content="0;URL='https://download.sketchapp.com/sketch-68.2-102594.zip
```

what I am looking to get is:

```
68.2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: something like `...|  awk 'NR==1{sub(/^.*-/,"",$3);sub(/-.*$/,"",$3);print $3}'` ... `$0` may work as well as `$3` or the `sub()`s. Good luck.

Comment: for exampe: `grep "something" | awk 'NR==1{print}'` can be written to one command `awk '/something/ && (NR==1){print}'`

Comment: ...or you could get what you want with one grep to print what lies after the pattern, e.g. `grep -oP '(?<=download.sketchapp.com/sketch-)[^-]+'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to extract the number after your pattern, only for the first matcing row. You can use one `grep` command:

```
... | grep -oPm1 '(?<=download.sketchapp.com/sketch-)[^-]+' file
```

or as this is the 3rd field of your 1st `curl` output row you want, you can use one awk command (split field using hyphen as separator to array and print the element in the middle):

```
awk '/download.sketchapp.com/sketch-/ && NR==1 {split($3,a,"-"); print a[2]; exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
/usr/bin/curl -s sketch*.zip "https://www.sketch.com/downloads/mac/" | \
    sed -n 's!.*download.sketchapp.com/sketch-\([^-]*\).*!\1!p;' | \
    head -1
```

head is to get rid of multiple matches. sed command extracts non-hyphen characters after `download.sketchapp.com/sketch-`.